# In Flutter How to change the specific widget in a list builder after clicking the button

Tags: flutter, listview

I am beginner in flutter and I want to change the widget in my list after clicking the button in that same list. I tried but when I clicked the button in the list the widget was changed in a whole list and I want to update that widget in specific list.

Please help me.

Comment: Get the item as `list[itemAtIndex]` and update its value / properties with a `setState()` call.

Comment: could you please, provide the code for the  `ListView`